# Error while loading shared libraries: cv2.so

Tags: opencv, shared-libraries

I installed OpenCV on my Raspberry, I wrote the first sample program (http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html). It compile correctly, but if executed from Code::Blocks it gave an error because miss an argument that must be given from CLI.

```
./First image.jpg
```

The program should only show an image in a window. The problem is that when I try to execute it from CLI I get an error.

```
./First: error while loading shared libraries: cv2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

What should I do? Where could I find cv2.so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cv2.so should be someplace within the build directory. You can use `find <build folder> -name cv2.so` to locate it.

In order to get `./First image.jpg` to run sucessfully you'll need to ensure that the binary knows where it can find the library file. You can do this two ways:

- Any binary under linux automatically looks in the current directory for its dynamic libraries. By making a symlink from cv2.so to the directory the binary is in, `ln -s ~/path/to/cv2.so .`, it will be found.
- Instead of making the library be the binary it will look, you can tell the binary to look someplace else by using the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment argument, e.g. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/path/to/ ./First image.jpg`.